# GROUP_CONCAT slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT query.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(query.gene,'None'), '(', query.loc, '|', COALESCE(query.typ,'unknown'), ')') AS outt
FROM (
  SELECT genes.loc,
  genes.typ, genes.abans, genes.despres, genes.gene, 
  mutations.id,mutations.chr,mutations.pos,mutations.ref,
  mutations.ale,mutations.g001,mutations.g002,mutations.g003,
  .... (snipped hundreds of denormalized fields)....
  FROM genes
  INNER JOIN mutations
  ON genes.id=mutations.id
  WHERE (mutations.g001>=0.40 
    AND mutations.g002>=0.40 AND mutations.g003>=0.40 
    AND mutations.g004>=0.40 AND mutations.g005>=0.40 
    AND mutations.g006>=0.40 AND mutations.g007>=0.40 
    AND mutations.g008>=0.40 AND mutations.g011>=0.40  
    AND mutations.g012>=0.40 AND mutations.g013>=0.40  
    AND mutations.g014>=0.40 AND mutations.g015>=0.40  
    AND ....(you get the idea)...
    AND mutations.g105>=0.40
  ) LIMIT 0, 100
) AS query 
GROUP BY query.id
```

I do a `GROUP_CONCAT` in that query and it works quite well. The problem is that I want 100 rows, while I get less that 100 rows due to the `GROUP BY`. When trying to apply `GROUP_CONCAT` directly to the inner query, it is extremely slow. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is don't use GROUP_CONCAT, and instead do this kind of stuff in your application level code.

Comment: You will have to change your logic, possibly in the `WHERE` clause, to filter out fewer records.

Comment: "I want 100 rows, while I get less that 100 rows due to the GROUP BY"??? This makes no sense. Either you want a result row per ID or not. If not, then what do you want? One row per gene type maybe? Simply change your GROUP BY, so as to get what you want.

Comment: The table design looks weird. Tables genes and mutations share the ID? So a gene is a mutation or a mutation is a gene? That doesn't sound right. And what are these g001 to g105? Are there exactly 105 *somethings* in a mutation? I am not saying it's wrong, but it does look fishy.

Comment: WHERE is applied to rows ,GROUP BY, well, creates groups.groups!=rows,clarify your question

Comment: @Thordten: it makes sense if mutations.id is the foreign key to genes.id, just a bad naming convention.

Comment: @user2979409: Why do you think it's GROUP_CONCAT which is slow rather than the nested query? Did you measure it? Your table structure is heavily denormalized and impossible to index efficiently for this query. Also, you'll have trouble representing different sized genes. You are using a LIMIT without any ORDER BY - which will give unpredictable results.